# Shallow renderer spits empty react-native component

Tags: javascript, react-native, enzyme

Im trying to test a react-native app with enzyme :

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground, Image, TextInput, Platform, ScrollView} from 'react-native'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import LoginForm from '../LoginForm.js';
import Root from '../../Root.js'
import StylishInput from '../common/StylishInput';


it('shows a login form', () => {
  const wrapped = shallow(<Root><LoginForm /></Root>);
  console.log(wrapped)
  const componentInstance = wrapped.instance();
  componentInstance.componentWillMount();
  expect(wrapped.find(StylishInput).length).toEqual(2);
  expect(wrapped.find(TextInput).length).toEqual(2);
})
```

However wrapped is always an empty component and componentInstance null. I dont understand as LoginForm does exist and Root is a component I created to wrap my tested components inside provider. 
Here's a link to the all project if necessary :
[https://github.com/davidgeismar/timeo-mobile/blob/enzyme/src/components/**tests**/LoginForm.test.js](https://github.com/davidgeismar/timeo-mobile/blob/enzyme/src/components/__tests__/LoginForm.test.js)

Answer (score 0):

**I would love to see what your root looks like in order to be more accurate, but here is a guess.**

```
//Try something like this. I dont know how you root looks like, but im making a few guesses.
it('shows a login form', () => {
  //try shallowing it like this with props if you have any. I am guessing that Loginform is inside of you Root
  const wrapped = shallow(<Root {...props}/>);
  console.log(wrapped)
  const componentInstance = wrapped.instance();
  //do not use componentWillMount as it is deprecated use componentDidMount instead
  componentInstance.componentDidMount();
  expect(wrapped.find(LoginForm).length).toEqual(1);
  expect(wrapped.find(TextInput).length).toEqual(2);
})
```